# How to obtain timestamp and user id from .osm file in PostGIS enabled Postgres database

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

At present, [osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) seems to
ignore the timestamp and user id of the elements, a serious drawback 
for some applications. According to a 
[bug report](https://trac.openstreetmap.org/ticket/4894) this is not
solved by the addition of the `--extra-attributes` tag.
I've just tested this in osm2pgsql 0.83.0 and am wondering if there is a good way around it?

My plan B is to do pre-filtering with [osmosis](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis) and then load the data into R using [osmar](http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/). Still, it would be nice to have the PostGIS option working also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default.style file has this annotation:

> There are some special database columns that **if present in the .style file**
>   will be populated by osm2pgsql.
>   These are
>
> osm_user, osm_uid, osm_version, osm_timestamp - datatype text. Used with the
>   --extra-attributes option to include metadata in the database. **If importing
>   with both --hstore and --extra-attributes the meta-data will end up in the
>   tags hstore column regardless of the style file.**

I have not tested it myself, but adding those tags in the style file **and** ommitting `--hstore` should work.  `--extra-attributes` is not enough.

Comment: It sounds like adding the --hstore tag should work, but when I type: osm2pgsql --hstore --extra-attributes -d Cycway GB_cycleways.pbf 
, it results in an error: failed: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist

Comment: But without --hstore and with the following lines added, it works: 147 node,way   osm_user     text         linear
148 node,way   osm_uid      text         linear
149 node,way   osm_timestamp text        linear The final command was thus: osm2pgsql --extra-attributes -S default.style -d Cycway GB_cycleways.pbf

Comment: The --hstore option requires to run share\contrib\hstore.sql once when setting up the database. But the metadata will then only be in the hstore column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a heavy solution/workaround for a smal problem, but you can try to work with full planet extracts: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/full

Answer (score 0):

First, your OSM data needs user_id. [Geofabrik downloads](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html) page notes this:

> The OpenStreetMap data files provided on this server do not contain the user names, user IDs and changeset IDs of the OSM objects because these fields are assumed to contain personal information about the OpenStreetMap contributors and are therefore subject to data protection regulations in the European Union.
> Extracts with full metadata are available to OpenStreetMap contributors only.

Than you have  two options:

1. adding this three lines to style file:

- node,way osm_user text linear
- node,way osm_uid text linear
- node,way osm_timestamp text linear

In this case, you don't need `--hstore`

2. storing extra attributes in hstore field. First **enable hstore extension in postgres database**. In osm2pgsql use `--extra-attributes --hstore`

My code: `osm2pgsql --slim --extra-attributes --hstore -c -d OSM -U user --password -H localhost -S "c:\default.style" c:\Europe-latest-internal.osm.pbf`